# How to pass html tags' content to google chart datatable

Tags: html, jquery-ui, charts

I am trying to add a google pie chart in my web page. I have my results calculated and stored in several html span tags.
How could i pass those values to google chart in order to draw a pie char accordingly.

```
    <div id="emission">
    <div>Air Travel: <span id="airtotalresult"></span></div>
    <div>Ground Travel: <span id="groundtotalresult"></span></div>
    <div>Home Energy: <span id="hometotalresult"></span></div>
    <div>Diet: <span id="diettotalresult"></span></div>
    <div>Expenditure:<span id="shoppingtotalresult"></span> </div>
    <div>Waste: <span id="wastetotalresult"></span></div>

     <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        // ... draw the chart...
    </script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a pie chart following googles tutorial https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

For a flat pie chart add this in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['option 1', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['option 2',     11],
      ['option 3',      2],
      ['option 4',  2],
      ['option 5', 2],
      ['option 6',    7] //name and the data
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'chart name' //name of the chart
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Then paste this in the body

```
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```